# Regex - Trimming whitespace from start and end of line

Tags: regex

Link: http://regexone.com/example/5

It asks: Write a simple regular expression to capture the content of each line, without the extra whitespace.

What I have is a mess with a bunch of \S+, is there an elegant way to solve this problem?

Comment: `^\s*(.*)\s*$`? `\s*(.*)` is enough to solve that test case.

Comment: If you want a good answer here, please post all relevant data here, means examples that show the problem, what you have tried and where is your problem. But this is a weird test case on that page, there is no whitespace at the end.

Comment: What is "too localized" about this question? Is stripping whitespace an "extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable"? I vote to reopen!

Comment: This is a decent regex to use to trim leading and trailing whitespace:  `^\s*(.+?)\s*$`  Note the non-greedy center expression so the trailing whitespace can be properly cut.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Writing regular expressions may seem like a black art, but it's actually quite simple; the most important step is to identify with surgical precision exactly what you do and do not want to match, then say just what you mean (no more and no less).

Another tip: when using `*` or `+` qualifiers, especially with "wildcard" characters like `.`, always remember that part of the regex may "run past" the part which you wanted to match, perhaps matching the entire string. Often, the simplest solution is to use a reluctant qualifier like `*?` or `+?` instead. (The most common regexp bugs are those which make the regexp match *when you didn't want it to* or *more than you wanted to*.)

In this case, you want "the content of each line, without extra whitespace". That's not quite precise enough. What is "extra whitespace"? Trailing and leading whitespace? If so...

Let's express that in completely precise, non-ambiguous terms. What you basically have is:

1. A region of whitespace characters (possibly empty)
2. Either:
   a) Nothing.
   b) A single non-whitespace character.
   c) A region which starts and ends with non-whitespace characters.
3. A region of whitespace characters (possibly empty)

Can you express that as a regex? Try doing so and posting it here, then I'll give you some feedback.

Comment: As mentioned above, the \s*(.*) solves it fine, but I don't think it's correct since it selects whitespace and everything after?

Comment: Yes, it's not correct. Try translating the description I wrote for you (1, 2, and 3) into a correct regex.

Comment: This is what I have from the description: 1. [^\s*]?

2. ^\S*$

3. [^\s*]?

Comment: Basically: Ignore any whitespace, take any non white space character that ends with non-whitespace characters, ignore whitespace characters at the end.

Comment: There are a few problems you need to fix. 1. Why are you using a character class (`[]`) for the first part? Do you know how character classes work? If not, please research before you come back. 2. The `?` for the first part is unnecessary, since `*` can match 0 characters. 3. A "region which starts and ends with non-whitespace" is different from a "region of non-whitespace". Say the string is `"  a word "`. `\S*` can match `"a"` or `"word"`, but not `"a word"`. 4. You have the `$` anchor in the wrong place. 5. The 3rd part has the same problems as the 1st.

Comment: 1. according to the regexone.com website, [^abc] = not a, b, or c. So my thinking is "no spaces of 0 or more". 2. Thanks, that makes sense. 3. hmm I tried looking for something that matches a group of words with spaces.. Maybe this is a closer solution? ([^\s]+)([\w*\s]+\.*)

Comment: This one seems to work fine: ``[^\s*](.*)[^\s*]`` https://www.evernote.com/shard/s236/sh/e3f4a279-8628-452d-97e1-ba2880edf7a3/867417fd3e51b52af052419dd76246fa

Comment: `[^abc]` means "any single character which is not a, b, or c". `[\s*]` means "any single character which is not whitespace or *". If you want any number of non-whitespace chars, you could use `[^\s]*`, but `\S*` is more concise. Aside from that, `\S*.*\S*` will work -- note that it just matches the desired part of the string, rather than matching the whole string and picking out the desired part with a capturing group. This means that if the string is entirely whitespace, the regex will fail to match. Do you understand how and why it works?

Comment: I see, instead of recognizing -- what is not -- to get -- what is --: ``[^\s*]``.. we might as well go straight for what is: ``\S*``.  So it starts finding beginning and ending of any non-whitespace char, then anything in between. The regexone.com site doesn't recognize this solution.  Testing the: ``\S*.*\S*`` on regexbuddy.. it still selects the whitespaces (tabs, spaces). 

``\S*.*\S*`` -> http://goo.gl/qZgjc

``[^\s*].*[^\s*]`` -> http://goo.gl/d4uAj (isn't this the lesson intent?)

Comment: OK, I tried it and see what the problem is. The `\S*` matches 0 characters, then `.*` matches the whole line, then the next `\S*` matches 0 characters. This works: `\S(.*\S)?`. It seems you still don't quite understand what `*` does inside a character class: `[a*]` does NOT mean "any number of a's" -- rather, it means "a single a or a single \*". Ironically, this misunderstanding made your `[^\s*].*[^\s*]` regex (mostly) work -- it just breaks down when the desired region starts or ends with "*", or when the desired region is just 1 character long.

Comment: I understand how ``*`` behaves differently in character class now.. ``\S.*\S`` <- this works even if there are white spaces at the end of the sentence. An even easier way to do this is probably store each line and use the trim command to remove whitespaces.. but we want to be Regex Ninjas ;). Thanks for the walkthrough Alex!

Comment: No problem! Good luck with your studies!

Comment: @AlexD, what if we only have a single digit? ;P e.g. `"    i    "`

Comment: @Mehrad, if you use `\S(.*\S)?` to match the desired part of the string, it still works. The optional part won't match anything, but that is fine.