# JMeter Regular Expression - Remove leading spaces

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have a regular expression that captures 17 matches. But these matches also include the spaces (leading or trailing).

Tried using [\s*]. But, some spaces still remain.

Screenshots are attached for your reference.

Please help.

Regards,
Ajith

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oXQS.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqZua.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link may help: [Regex - Trimming whitespace from start and end of line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293841/regex-trimming-whitespace-from-start-and-end-of-line)

`\S(.*\S)?` should trim leading and trailing whitespace

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to come up with a comprehensive answer without seeing your response data (at least partial)

Try the following regular expression:

```
edison-system?\s*(.+?)?\s*?/
```

Where:

- `?\s` means optional whitespace
- `+` - zero or more times

More information:

- [JMeter Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Java Regular Expressions Quantifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html)